# VS Code remote ssh to Docker on RasPi needs launch.json edit for --privilegef

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

So I'm developing an app utilizing bluez bluetooth in a docker container on a raspberry pi running Openmediavault/ Portainer. I'm using VSCode via ssh to the raspberry pi and I'm sharing the /var/run/dbus volume from the host to the container which works fine if I build the container outside of vscode in a terminal window using: docker run --privileged -d-ti --name mycontainername myimagename:latest
I would much prefer to run the same privileged arguments from vscode but can't find the proper syntax add to the launch.json file to accomplish this.
Any help out there please?

Tried using IntelliSense to find ARG syntax examples to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer in the 'settings' section of the Docker extension. (home>user>.config>Code>User>{} settings.json)
I changed the line:

"docker.commands.runInteractive": "${containerCommand} run --rm -it ${exposedPorts} ${tag}",

to:
"docker.commands.runInteractive": "${containerCommand} run --privileged --rm -it ${exposedPorts} ${tag}",

All is once again well in my little world.